# how to configure Azure CosmosDB settings to latest bot framework design?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

This is my startup now it uses memory storage. How to use cosmos settings?
I can't find any sample on the documentation. Except writing [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) writing directy to storage.

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();

        services.AddSingleton<UserState>();

        services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();

        services.AddSingleton<IBotServices, BotServices>(); 

        services.AddTransient<MainDialog>();

        services.AddTransient<IBot, DialogBot<MainDialog>>();
    }
```

before i was doing it like this:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {       
        services.AddBot<BasicBot>(options =>
        {
                var cosmosServiceEndpoint = Configuration.GetSection("CosmosServiceEndpoint").Value;
                var cosmosDBKey = Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDBKey").Value;
                var cosmosDBDatabaseName = Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDBDatabaseName").Value;
                var cosmosDBCollectionNameUserState = Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDBCollectionNameUserState").Value;

                IStorage dataStoreConverstationState = 
                new CosmosDbStorage(new CosmosDbStorageOptions
                {
                    AuthKey = cosmosDBKey,
                    CollectionId = cosmosDBCollectionNameUserState,
                    CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri(cosmosServiceEndpoint),
                    DatabaseId = cosmosDBDatabaseName,
                });
                var conversationState = new ConversationState(dateStoreConversationState)
                options.State.Add(conversationState);

                IStorage dataStoreUserState =
                new CosmosDbStorage(new CosmosDbStorageOptions
                {
                    AuthKey = cosmosDBKey,
                    CollectionId = cosmosDBCollectionNameUserState,
                    CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri(cosmosServiceEndpoint),
                    DatabaseId = cosmosDBDatabaseName,
                });
                var userState = new UserState(dataStoreUserState);
                options.State.Add(userState);
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty similar and the docs you pointed to actually show a successful way to do it. If you'd like to use Dependency Injection, you'd use something like:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        [...]
        //services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();
        var cosmosServiceEndpoint = Configuration.GetSection("CosmosServiceEndpoint").Value;
        var cosmosDBKey = Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDBKey").Value;
        var cosmosDBDatabaseName = Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDBDatabaseName").Value;
        var cosmosDBCollectionNameUserState = Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDBCollectionNameUserState").Value;

        services.AddSingleton<IStorage>(sp => new CosmosDbStorage(new CosmosDbStorageOptions()
        {
            AuthKey = cosmosDBKey,
            CollectionId = cosmosDBCollectionNameUserState,
            CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri(cosmosServiceEndpoint),
            DatabaseId = cosmosDBDatabaseName,
        }));
    [...]
```

Just make sure your Cosmos settings are in `appsettings.json`

Comment: I forgot to mention that yes i would like to use dependency injection. Thank you!